# Magento unit testing how to mock/load/use a product

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, phpunit

I am using some very basic unit testing in a magento module and do not want to use any of the two main testing modules/frameworks for magento.

My question is relatively simple though.  In a unit test how do i load a product to check that it has a certain property and that the value is not null?

Within my test i have Mage initialised but as the module may be used in different projects, i cannot realistically hard code a product id to load.

So, how can this be achieved?

The best I can come up with so far is to load a full product collection and iterate over each checking for the required attribute.

Comment: Is the assertion that for every product which has a specific attribute in its attribute set, that a value is set for that attribute?

Comment: I was thinking that there will be two tests: 1. Check that the property exists 2. That the value is not null.

Comment: Curious about "the goal". Does the test pass only if ALL appropriate products check out ok, or does it pass if one appropriate product passes?

Comment: I suppose thats a matter of choice/design. I could check 1, 3, 10, all etc.  If my module introduces a new property to the catalog/product model, should every product be tested or is it enought to test a subset?  And this is part of the problem for me.  If i dont test all, how do i specify those product ids to actually test

Comment: "should every product be tested" - up to you. It's cheap & easy to do, I'd imagine. Most important would be correct install script and necessary validation through the attribute's backend model.

Comment: Would mock objects be suitable here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20822/discussion-between-benmarks-and-marty-wallace)

Comment: please post the code that you have written to date. I suspect you will actually find that using the EcomDev PHPUnit or other testing framework will turn out to be much quicker, and certainly better in the long run

Comment: IMO, the question is not clear. Do you want to test your code or the integrity of your data?

Comment: You can use a Ecomdev_PHPUnit Module which provides a model mock. http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/02/01/phpunit-and-magento-yes-you-can.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a product inside a transaction then roll the transaction back up after you get your unit test result.

At the very least I tried something similar to what you were doing, and ended up something like this:

```
try {
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $write->beginTransaction();

// 1. create your product
// 2. test it. 
// 3. important: Throw an exception with the test results for example:
//               throw new Exception("Test <{$testName}> : {$result}"); 
// NOTE: Throwing the exception is important to end this with a rollback, always.

    $write->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    mage::log(__METHOD__ . ':' . __LINE__ . ": {$e->getMessage()}");
    $write->rollback();
}
```

Good luck!